# angular promise execution sequence controlling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement JavaScript functions asynchronously using angularjs in a specific manner as shown in below image.

[image]

I tried few options without any luck http://jsfiddle.net/pb53cafy/4/

Sample Code:

```
function PromiseCtrl($scope, $q, $timeout) {
//
 var Afunction = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve("Success A");
        }, 1000);
        return deferred.promise;
    };

   var Bfunction = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve("Success B");
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    $scope.result = "Waiting";
    $q.all([
            Afunction(),
            Bfunction()
        ]).then(function(value) {
        $scope.result = value;       
    }, function(reason) {
        $scope.result = reason;
    });
    //Remaining code ...

}
```

appreciate your help on this

EDIT : Modified with the code what I was looking for http://jsfiddle.net/pb53cafy/11/

Comment: If you always want to move forward once A has returned, just wait on A, not both of them. What is the purpose of B? Fallback in case A fails?

Comment: Please use the built-in Stack Snippets for runnable examples, rather than off-site resources. Stack Snippets are the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: For this case there is a overhead of A to complete, I want the process as fast as possible by making them Async.

Comment: That's fine. It doesn't answer the question about B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create another function to control the execution process:

```
function execute() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var bFinished;

    var aPromise = Afunction().then(function(aRes) {
        if(!bFinished) deferred.resolve(aRes);
        return aRes;
    }).catch(deferred.reject);

    Bfunction().then(function(bRes) {
        bFinished = true;
        return aPromise.then(function(aRes) {
            deferred.resolve(bRes + " and " + aRes);
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

If A finishes first, it doesn't wait for B.

If B finishes first, it waits for A to finish too.

Comment: Thanks.. this helped.. i am able to get the desired output using this appraoch... http://jsfiddle.net/pb53cafy/10/

Answer (score 2):

Since you always want to proceed when A completes, just wait for A, without waiting for B.

You haven't said what B is for, but:

1. If it's a fallback in case A fails, you'd chain A's failure handler to B's promise
2. If it's just something else you'll need at some point down-the-line, return its promise with A's result; whatever needs it down-the-line can hook to it

Example of #1:

```
var a = Afunction();
var b = Bfunction();
a.catch(function() {
    return b; // A failed, chain to B
}).then(function(value) {
    // ...rest of code...
    $scope.result = value;       
}, function(reason) {
    $scope.result = reason;
});
```

Example of #2:

```
var a = Afunction();
var b = Bfunction();
a.then(function(value) {
    // ...rest of code...
    // We're at the point we need b
    return b.then(function() {
        // ...possibly more code here...
        $scope.result = value;       
    });
}, function(reason) {
    $scope.result = reason;
});
```

In both cases I made a point of starting A first (it can matter if you're doing something like HTTP requests). If that's not important, you can get rid of the `a` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest that you answer the questions you have been asked in the comments. Without those, it's hard to give you good advice.

However, assuming that you want the result of B *when it is available before A* and can do without it when it's not, then you can do this:

```
$scope.result = "Waiting";
var bResult = null;

var pa = Afunction();
var pb = Bfunction();

pb.then(function (br) {
    bResult = br;
});

pa.then(function (ar) {
    // if B finished first, its value will be in the 
    // bResult closure variable.
    // if A finished first, bResult will be null.

    $scope.result = ar;       
}, function(reason) {
    $scope.result = reason;
});
```

Comment: Between the two of us, I think we have it covered. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I will answer to your question from ES Promise perspective, but you can adapt it to deferreds as well.

Three basic primitives which solve similar tasks are:

- [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) takes an iterable of promises and wait for all of them to resolve or for any one of them to reject. This primitive treats all input promises as equal, but that is not your case, where `A` and `B` got different meaning. However, please note how it works in rejection case.
- [`settle all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-settle) is a non-standard analogue of `Promise.all` which awaits all rejections as well as resolves (contradict to previous one). It also treats all input promises as equal.
- [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) awaits for first resolving or rejection. Also treats all inputs as equal. This one is most similar to your case, please note how it handles rejections.

Looks like the `A` input in your case is more important than `B`, so we can't use any of «symmetric» primitives, we need some hand-written primitive to the resque.

```js
// first, let's invoke both A and B producers,
// because we need parallel execution
var p_a = AFunction(…)
var p_b = BFunction(…)

// if p_b resolves earlier, we can save it
var shared_b
p_b.then(value => shared_b = value)

// because A is more like a leader, let's wait for it,
// we can't proceed without it in both scenarios,
// we can't use `all` or `race`
var p_pair = p_a.then(value =>
{
    return [ value, shared_b ]
})

p_pair.then(([a, b]) =>
{
    console.log(a, ': A is always here')
    console.log(b, ': B only if was ready fast enough')
})
```

`p_pair` is now `Promise<[ A, B | undefined ]>`.

`B` rejections are ignored.

You can adapt it to deferreds in simple manner, like your `AFunction` and `BFunction` are.